# Operator version of Birkhoff ergodic theorem

Tags: pr.probability, operator-theory, ergodic-theory

Suppose that $(\Omega,\mathcal{E},P)$ is a probability space and suppose that we have a measurable operator $T:\Omega\to\Omega$.

Recall that $T$ is said to be egodic if:

1. $T$ is measure preserving: i.e. $P(T^{-1}E)=P(E)$;
2. $T$ is zero-one: $E=T^{-1}(E)$ implies that $P(E)\in\{0,1\}$;

Now consider the operator $S_T:L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{E},P)\to L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{E},P)$ given by $S_T(f):=f\circ T$.

Then the Birkhoff theorem tells us that, if $T$ is ergodic, then
$$
\lim_t \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} S_T^j(f)=E[f]\quad\text{ a.s..} 
$$

It is known that $T$ is ergodic if and only if $S_T$ satisfies

1. $E[S_T(f)]=E[f]$;
2. $S_T(f)=f$ implies that $f$ is a constant a.s..

My question is: Is the claim in the Birkhoff theorem still true when an operator $S$ satisfies 1 and 2 above, but we do not necessarily have that $S=S_T$ for some ergodic transformation?

That is, suppose that $S_T:L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{E},P)\to L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{E},P)$ is any linear function that satisfies 1 and 2 above, is it true that 
$$
\lim_t \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} S^j(f)=E[f]\quad\text{ a.s..} 
$$
?

If true, can you give me some reference?

Comment: That $S$ be "any linear function" is an extremely weak condition. If you assume, however, that $S$ if positive (in the sense that $Sf \ge 0$ whenever $f \ge 0$), then the answer is "yes". Is $S$ positive in the situation you have in mind?

Comment: Yes @JochenGlueck , $S$ could be also positive. Why is  the answer yes? Could you give me a reference?

Comment: Probably we also need to assume that $S(1)=1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right that the assertion is false without an assumption of the type $S1=1$ (apparently, I was not reading carefully enough; I thought you're first assumption was $Sf=f$ if and only if $f$ is constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer consists of two parts:

**Part I.** The answer is *no*, in general. Here is a counterexample:

**Example.** Let $\Omega = \{1,2\}$ and let $P$ by $1/2$ times the counting measure. The matrix
\begin{align*}
  S =
  1/2 \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
fulfils both assumptions 1. and 2., but
$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} S^k f = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k f = \frac{2^n-1}{n}$ if $f$ equals the eigenvector $(1,-1)^T$ of $S$ (for the eigenvalue $2$).

**Part II.** The answer is *yes* if the operator $S$ is *positive* in the sense that $S f \ge 0$ whenever $f \ge 0$ and if, in addition, $S1 = 1$.

This follows, for instance, from Theorem 11.4 in [Eisner, Farkas, Haase, Nagel: *Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory* (2015)].

**EDIT in response to a comment.** The reference quoted above only shows almost everywhere convergence of the Cesàro means, without giving detailed information about the limit function. The fact that the limit function is given by $E[f] \cdot 1 = \langle 1, f\rangle \cdot 1$ can for instance be seen as follows (maybe there is also a more direct argument, but I find the following argument rather natural from an operator theoretic point of view):

- Order intervals in $L^1$-spaces are weakly compact (see for instance [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292938/102946)). In particular, the S-invariant order interval $[-c \cdot 1, c \cdot 1]$ is weakly compact for each number $c \ge 0$.
- Hence, it follows for instance from Corollary~A.5 in [Engel, Nagel: *One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations* (2000)] that all orbits of $S$ are relatively weakly compact.
- This implies in turn that the Cesàro means of $S$ converge strongly to a bounded linear operator $Q$, i.e. $S$ is *mean ergodic* (see *Eberlein's ergodic theorem*).
- By a standard result from operator theory, this implies that the fixed space of $S$ separates the fixed space of the dual operator $S'$. Hence, as the fixed space of $S$ is one dimensional by assumption, the fixed space of the dual operator is one-dimensional, too, i.e. it is spanned by the function $1$.
- It is easy to see that $Q$ is a projection whose range consists of the fixed points of $S$ and that the range of the dual projection $Q'$ consists of the fixed points of $S'$. Hence, we have $Q = 1 \otimes 1$, i.e. $Qf = \langle 1, f\rangle \cdot 1$ for each $f \in L^1(\Omega,P)$.
- Hence, $(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} S^kf)$ converges in norm to $\langle 1, f \rangle \cdot 1$, and as quoted above the sequence converges almost everywhere to a function $g \in L^1(\Omega,P)$. This implies that actually $g = \langle 1,f\rangle \cdot 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes things much more clear. However, I have another question. I read Theorem 11.4 in Eisner et al.'s book. This theorem tells us that the limit exists, but how can we know that this limit is exactly $E[f]$? Sorry, I do not know in deep ergodic theory.

Comment: @Littlefield: I added an argument that shows why the limit is of the claimed form. Unfortunately, I don't have much time right now, so I was a bit sketchy. Please leave another comment if you need more details or references; I'll then add them next week.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time for this outline of the proof. I will read carefully. By the way, I have realized that in that post on weak compactness of order intervals, we both interchanged also comments there already. That is a funny coincidence.

Comment: Theorem 8.24 in [Eisner, Farkas, Haase, Nagel: Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory (2015)] that the limit is in L1. So you get directly the last item in last part of your answer.